# Kohana Sessions data does not persist across pages in chrome and IE browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, session, google-chrome, kohana, persist

Kohana Session data does not persist across pages opened in Chrome and IE browsers

the same works fine in a Firefox browser

Kohana version used is 2.3

session config files hold

```
$config['driver'] = 'native';

/**
 * Session storage parameter, used by drivers.
 */
$config['storage'] = '';

/**
 * Session name.
 * It must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores. At least one letter must be present.
 */
$config['name'] = 'NITWSESSID';

/**
 * Session parameters to validate: user_agent, ip_address, expiration.
 */
$config['validate'] = array();

/**
 * Enable or disable session encryption.
 * Note: this has no effect on the native session driver.
 * Note: the cookie driver always encrypts session data. Set to TRUE for stronger encryption.
 */
$config['encryption'] = FALSE;

/**
 * Session lifetime. Number of seconds that each session will last.
 * A value of 0 will keep the session active until the browser is closed (with a limit of 24h).
 */
$config['expiration'] = 2700;

/**
 * Number of page loads before the session id is regenerated.
 * A value of 0 will disable automatic session id regeneration.
 */
$config['regenerate'] = 0;

/**
 * Percentage probability that the gc (garbage collection) routine is started.
 */
$config['gc_probability'] = 2;
```

Help needed urgently

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think this should probably be a comment on your question, but I don't have that privilege yet.

Anyways, are you using the correct syntax to instantiate the session?

```
$this->session = Session::instance()
```

not

```
$this->session = new Session();
```

From http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/2225
Apparently the second works in firefox but causes issues in IE, says nothing about chrome.